# Is it possible to alter a downloaded .html file and display edited contents to UIWebView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

Im developing an iPhone App that downloads an .html file from an ftp server. Is it possible to edit the html file before rendering it in an UIWebView? The html file contains data that is not relevant so I would like to delete part of the content. If so, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In a few steps:

1. Perform the FTP request yourself, using `NSURLConnection`.
2. Get the HTML into a string, and modify it.
3. Invoke [`-loadHTMLString:baseURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a) to pass the modified document to the `UIWebView`.